# User login not linking to translated front page

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

On my front page I have a language selector (English / Spanish). The default language is English. If a user chooses Spanish and logs in he is redirected to the English version of the front page. How do I redirect them to the Spanish version of the front page?

I tried Rules but that did not work.

Comment: is there any argument in the url to make it in spanish ? something like ?lang=sp ?

Comment: Negative. The url ends in /es for the spanish version. Ex. Https://example.com/drupal/es

Comment: I don't understand when you said: "if a user chooses Spanish and logs in he is redirected" do you mean an anonymous ? if yes maybe it's because drupal prob didn't save the details of a non authenticated user. Does it keep the language for a authenticated user who choose Spanish and log off and log in again ?